# About diagonal linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a linear transformation $T$ from  $V$ to $V$ where $\dim(V) =n$.
Let $V_1 ,V_2 ......V_n$ be basis of $T$.

Now let $B$ be the  matrix of $T$ then  I see in my book that  $B$ is diagonal matrix iff
$T(v_1)=aV_1,\ \ .............,T(V_n)= bV_n$

i.e. $V_1 ,V_2,.....V_n$  must be eigenvectors of $T$.

But proof is not given......
So I start doing proof....

Then I only do that thing i.e..
$T(V_1) =(a,0,0,    ......   0)$
$T(V_2)= (0,b,0,.............0)$
$\dots$
$T(V_n)=(0,0,.................n)$.
Please help me give me its proof .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $V_1,\dots,V_n$ then, $T(V_i)$ should be the $i$th column of $B$. Since $B$ is diagonal, the $i$th column of $B$ is $(0,\dots ,a_i,\dots,0) = a_iV_i$ where the nonzero element is in the $i$th row. Hence, $$T(V_i) = a_iV_i$$ This argument also works in reverse completing the proof.

Comment: I understand all but how we write this step.                                  (0,…,ai,…,0)=aiVi

Comment: Recall that if you have coordinates with respect to a basis $V_1,\dots, V_n$, then $$(c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n) = c_1V_1+c_2V_2+\cdots +c_nV_n$$

Comment: Thanks... I done  it.....